# Get name of object calling MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to get the name of the currently running proc or any other object that called my proc in MySQL? In MS SQL Server, you'd use...

```
SELECT Object_name(@@PROCID);
```

Is there an MySQL / MariaDB equivalent?

Comment: Where have you researched this? Some initial queries on Google give nothing so I'd hazard a guess this can't be done (?)

Comment: @Martin Google and stackoverflow